# Error first time fragment is displayed with cardview

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

I have an error the first time that my fragment with cardviews is shown, they become much larger and only fit 2 on the screen, that is, only one row of two columns when they should show 6, first I saw that it happened and now I I realized that when re-entering the fragment since this is the one by default, if I re-enter if it is shown as it should, this fragment is inside a navigation draw
I attach a capture of how it looks at the beginning, when entering the application:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2pQZ.png)

And in the next one it looks like this when I re-enter the fragment or I refresh it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFnuO.png)

Here I leave you as seen in the android designer:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77JR9.png)

And finally the xml of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".NumericalMethods.NonlinearEquations.NonlinearEquationsFragment"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_ne"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_nonlinear_ecuations"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Resolucion de \nEcuaciones No lineales "
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_nonlinear_ecuations">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_fp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pf" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Punto Fijo"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/car_nr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_nr"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Newton Raphson"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_sec"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_sec"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="La secante"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/car_fake_pos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pos_falsa"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Posicion Falsa"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_bisec"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_bisection"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Biseccion"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_muller"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_muller"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Muller"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And emphasize that it only happens when the application starts, and when I take a step back, when I say this I mean the button this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ctWr.png)

My Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Aplicacion Realizada por E.R.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.nav_ne, R.id.nav_sne, R.id.nav_fai, R.id.nav_id, R.id.nav_edo, R.id.nav_edp), drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

My mobile_navigartion.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_ne">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_ne"
        android:name="com.yr.mnlite.NumericalMethods.NonlinearEquations.NonlinearEquationsFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_ne"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_nonlinear_equations" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_sne"
        android:name="com.yr.mnlite.NumericalMethods.SistemNonlinearEquations.SistemNonlinearEquationsFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_sne"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sistem_nonlinear_equations" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_fai"
        android:name="com.yr.mnlite.NumericalMethods.FunctionalApproximationAndInterpolation.FunctionalApproximationAndInterpolationFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_fai"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_functional_approximation_and_interpolation" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_id"
        android:name="com.yr.mnlite.NumericalMethods.IntegrationDifferentiation.IntegrationDifferentiationFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_id"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_integration_differentiation" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_edo"
        android:name="com.yr.mnlite.NumericalMethods.OrdinaryDifferentialEquations.OrdinaryDifferentialEquationsFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_edo"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_ordinary_differential_equations" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_edp"
        android:name="com.yr.mnlite.NumericalMethods.PartialDifferentialEquations.PartialDifferentialEquationsFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_edp"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_partial_differential_equations" />

</navigation>
```

Thank you all very much I am new to android.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
   <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_fp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        >
```

Comment: I remove the row and column 0?

Comment: I tried but still need to refresh the fragment

Comment: Can you provide ur activity nd fragments code.

Comment: Sure, but how do I upload it?

Comment: Just Copy Paste here.

Comment: It's already there, could you please check it out thanks.